# Solving logarithm with variable in base and exponent for x

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

$$ log_{1+\frac{0.0231}{x}}{5x} = 10/9$$

What is the solution to this equation and how would I approach the problem? For the purposes of the question, algebraic manipulation with log and exponential rules would be a preferred solution.

Comment: Maybe $$\log_{a}(b)=\frac{\ln b}{\ln a}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the equation is $$\log_{1+\frac{0.0231}{x}}({5x}) =\frac {10}9$$ consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=\log_{1+\frac{0.0231}{x}}({5x}) -\frac {10}9=\frac{\log (5 x)}{\log \left(1+\frac{0.0231}{x}\right)}-\frac {10}9$$ or 
$$g(x)=9\log (5 x)-10 \log \left(1+\frac{0.0231}{x}\right)$$ Compute the derivative and set it equal to $0$; this would give
$$g'(x_*)=0 \implies x_*=-\frac{1463}{30000}< 0$$ So, since $x >0$, $g(x)$ is an increasing function. Observe that $$g\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)=-10 \log \left(\frac{2231}{2000}\right)\approx -1.09303$$ 
$$g\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)=9 \log (2)-10 \log \left(\frac{4231}{4000}\right)\approx5.67688$$so the solution is just above $\frac{1}{5}$. Then, start Newton method to get the follosing iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.2000000000 \\
 1 & 0.2217834116 \\
 2 & 0.2231295997 \\
 3 & 0.2231340463
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If we consider the more general case of the equation
$$\log_{1+\frac{a}{x}}({bx}) =c$$ rewriting as above
$$g(x)=\log (b x)-c \log \left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)$$ and assuming that $a$ is small, we could expand the second logarithm as a very truncated Taylor series and get
$$g(x) \sim \log (b x)-\frac{a c}{x}$$ and its *approximate* zero would be given by
$$x \sim \frac{a c}{W(a b c)}$$ where appears Lambert function.

Now, if $0 \leq t \leq 1$, we have, as an *approximation*, $W(t) \sim \frac{t}{t+1}$ and then
$$x \sim a c+\frac{1}{b}$$ Applied to the present case, this would give
$$x \sim \frac{677}{3000}\approx 0.225667$$ which is not bad.

Comment: Great answer! However, I wonder if there is a simpler way to compute it using a calculator.

Comment: @TanishqBomman. Have a look at my edit.